# When is the joint density differentiable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

My question is the following: given a real random vector $X = (X_1,...,X_k)$ with differentiable marginal densities $f_1,...,f_k$, what extra conditions on the marginals are needed to ensure that the joint density $f_{1,...,2}$ exists and is differentiable? Reference suggestions for this type of problems will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no reason to conclude that a _joint_ density is even definable, let alone differentiable, from the knowledge that the marginal densities are differentiable functions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have refocused my question and will appreciate further comments.

Comment: The joint probability can be decomposed into copula (which characterize the dependence structure) and marginal distributions. Depending on the copula, your joint may or may not be differenitable; for example, if you make the joint be just independent product, then it will have a density and partial derivatives will exist

Comment: Ilya thank you so much. For some reason copula completely slipped my mind.